# Can I pass a typeclass dictionary to a function explicitly?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

Let’s say I have some typeclass:

```
data Foo = Foo deriving (Show)

class Monad m => MonadFoo m where
  getFoo :: m Foo
```

Since GHC implements typeclasses via dictionary passing (uses of `SPECIALIZE` notwithstanding), it effectively transforms `getFoo` into something like the following under the hood:

```
data MonadFooDict m = MonadFooDict { getFoo :: m Foo }
```

...and it inserts an additional argument at the beginning of calls to `getFoo` that threads the dictionary around.

Sometimes, I might want to pick an instance dynamically, so passing a dictionary myself might be desirable. I can simulate this myself by creating an instance that will thread the dictionary around for me.

```
newtype DynamicMonadFoo a = DynamicMonadFoo
    { runFoo :: MonadFooDict DynamicMonadFoo -> a }
  deriving ( Functor, Applicative, Monad
           , MonadReader (MonadFooDict DynamicMonadFoo) )

instance MonadFoo DynamicMonadFoo where
  getFoo = join $ asks _getFoo
```

Now, given some function with a `MonadFoo` constraint, I can use the `runFoo` function to pass it an explicit typeclass dictionary:

```
showCurrentFoo :: MonadFoo m => m String
showCurrentFoo = do
  foo <- getFoo
  return ("current foo: " ++ show foo)

ghci> runFoo showCurrentFoo MonadFooDict { _getFoo = return Foo }
"current foo: Foo"
```

This is really cool, but it seems like such a simple task that GHC might expose some sort of library to do this without all the boilerplate (and ideally in a way that would work more nicely with non-monadic typeclasses). Given that GHC has some “reflection-esque” capabilities like `Data.Typeable`, this doesn’t seem outside the realm of possibility, but I’m not sure if it actually exists in some form.

Do any existing built-ins or other libraries allow doing this more automatically?

Comment: You can with the new explicit type application extension, more details [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ExplicitTypeApplication)

Comment: @pdexter Unless I’m missing something, that seems unrelated to me—it seems mostly syntactic and about working with values at the type level exclusively, while this question is about passing a dynamic runtime value as a typeclass dictionary. However, I could be misinterpreting the link, in which case an answer demonstrating it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

There is an article on this at the School of Haskell:

[Reflecting values to types and back](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/thoughtpolice/using-reflection)

See the section towards the end entitled [Dynamically constructing type-class instances](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/thoughtpolice/using-reflection#dynamically-constructing-type-class-instances) and [But what about manual dictionaries?](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/thoughtpolice/using-reflection#but-what-about-manual-dictionaries-)

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please include the interesting content here.

Comment: This is neat, but ultimately it doesn’t seem like it really cuts boilerplate by all that much... in fact, it seems to complicate it considerably. [Compare these two implementations](https://gist.github.com/lexi-lambda/71ee8ea84127d8318a121c6acf49d331) for the difference. Of course, it looks like this approach can work a lot better for non-monadic typeclasses, and the performance bit mentioned in the post you linked is interesting. Otherwise, it doesn’t seem like you gain much here... is that accurate?

Comment: Also, I should probably mention that I found reading [Functional Pearl: Implicit Configurations](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/tr-15-04.pdf), the paper that inspired the reflection package, to be very approachable and helpful to groking the concepts at a higher level than sifting through the Core output.

Comment: @AlexisKing I think the link is the best we can do and it gives us a lot. Two classes altogether for all `* -> Constraint` classes and two instances for each class is pretty good, and `using` does exactly what you asked for.